# How do you read single chars from stdin in Python

Tags: python, stdin

There are a lot of great answers on how to read from `stdin` in python, but I just can't find anything about reading single characters instead of whole lines. Let me explain:

I need to read information send by an arduino on a serial port, which is forwarded to stdin. This information is processed and stored in a text file. I wrote the programm on the arduino, so I could change how the information is send. The plan was to send the information with an start- (`<`) and an endcharacter (`>`), so it would look like this: `<height:2342>`

There will also be a lot of irrelevant data being written, thats why I decided to use the above form, so the python script can detect the relevant information and capture it.

My python script would check every char individually for the start-character `<`, ideally as it is entered, and then capture the information until `>` is received. I tried getting the input using `inputchar = sys.stdin.read(1)`. But the problem here is that this reads from `stdin` forever, until a newline (`\n`) is captured, and then returns the first character entered.

I want this function to return the entered character as soon as it got send to `stdin`, and not wait for a newline. How do I achive this?

*Platform: Raspberry Pi Zero W, Raspbian Jessy, Python 2.7*

---

*I know I could use* `inputline = sys.stdin.readline()` *and change the Arduino programm to send a newline after the information. Then analyze the whole line (which could be very long) and extract the information. But I don't feel this would be a clean way of doing this.*

---

**Update on Serial Port:** Sadly I can't access the serial port directly from python because there is a second python script which has to write to the serial port. Since only one can access the port, the solution is to redirect the serial port to `stdin` and `stdout`. See my question [Access one Serial Port with two Python Scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441176/access-one-serial-port-with-two-python-scripts)

Comment: You would probably have better luck opening the serial port directly from Python (so that you have control over buffering, for example), rather than redirecting the port to stdin.

Comment: If you're using pyserial, I'm pretty sure that can [read single bytes from the serial port directly](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read).

Comment: this library handles just that --> https://pypi.org/project/getch/

Comment: `.read()` on a pipe (I presume that your redirection program uses pipes) will return immediately when data is available. It will not wait for a newline. My best guess is that the program that redirects the serial port is buffering its output. Perhaps it needs to call `.flush()` after it calls `.write()` on its output pipe.

Comment: related or duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Answer (score 4):

This is because your [terminal is in cooked mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_mode). You can use e.g. [tty.setcbreak](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tty.html#tty.setcbreak) or [curses.cbreak](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.cbreak) to disable the line buffering. This is a Unix thing, not particularly Python specific.

Example:

```
import sys, tty
tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
```

Note that this has other effects such as disabling echo and will persist when your program exits. Typically a higher level interface such as a curses context manager is used to handle key parsing (arrow keys, for instance, send escape sequences) and cleanup.

The primary command line tool outside of Python for this is [stty](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to set the TTY to raw mode.  I wanted to time the duration of a keypress and needed this so that I didn't have to hit the enter key:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime
import sys
import tty
import termios


# read a single character on a unix system
# https://exceptionshub.com/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user.html
def read_unix(count: int):
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ch = sys.stdin.read(count)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)

    return ch


while True:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    char = read_unix(1)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    delta = end - start
    print(f'char={char}, delta={delta}')
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdin.read(1)` is a correct approach.

Before you hit the enter, there is no input at `sys.stdin`. That line buffering is performed outside your program and you can do nothing about it if you want to use `sys.stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing...

Executing on my Raspbian - on an RPI2:

```
$ cat a.py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys

while True:
    print "Got", ord(sys.stdin.read(1))


$ echo -n "Test"  | hexdump -C
00000000  54 65 73 74                                       |Test|
00000004

$ # No newline in the data sent by echo, as shown by hexdump

$ echo -n "Test"  | python2 a.py
Got 84
Got 101
Got 115
Got 116
Got
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    print "Got", ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found
```

Basically, the `sys.stdin.read(1)` returns with whatever character was sent from stdin, without waiting for any newline.

Comment: I have reproduced it at Ubuntu. Typed "test" in the CLI manually - so nothing has been sent to stdin.

Comment: The CLI is not the same thing as a pipe sending data from a serial line - which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: I am not sure whether a pipe may work in cooked mode - which I expect to be responsible for the issue.

Comment: A pipe does not go through the terminal layer - this is why [pseutoterminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) exist, and openssh has a [-t switch](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#t).